# Questions about "as .. as"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, adverbs, questions, as

I am curious about the accuracy of the questions about "as .. as".

Examples;

> *Who are you as happy as?* (I am as happy as you)
>
> *Who do you go to school as often as?* (I go to school as often as you) or (as often as you do)
>
> *What is it based on the same structure as?* (It is based on the same structure as X)
>
> *What do you earn as much money as I do?* (I earn as much money as you earn) or (as much money as you can't imagine) etc.

Are these questions grammatical?

I think that the first two questions are correct but the other two questions are not correct.

They sound strange to me. What about your thoughts? Could you explain what the reason of your answer is? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I am as happy as **you**.  **Who** am I as happy as?
>
> It is based on the same structure as **DNA**.  **What** is it based on
>    the same structure as?
>
> I earn as much money as **you**.  **Who** do I earn as much money as?

You simply flip the sentence from the declarative to the interrogative, and use the appropriate interrogative pronoun.

I cannot imagine the declarative that produced your last interrogative, unless you meant to omit "money".

> I earn as much of it as you (do). What do I earn as much of as you (do)?

Praise?  Money?  Respect?